# C# Generics - Infer Type of static factory members

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to invoke static members of a class that uses generics without specifying the type and having the compiler infer them.

For example this is the generic class I want to use, with the Static Factory member:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T Member;

    // Constructor
    public GenericClass(T value)
    { 
        Member = value; 
    }

    // static factory method
    public static GenericClass<T> StaticFactory(T resultData) 
    { 
        return new GenericClass<T>(resultData); 
    }
}
```

If I try the following does not compile:

```
    public class Class1
    {
        public GenericClass<string> returnResult1()
        {
            return GenericClass.StaticFactory("Won't Compile, but it's clear that T is a string");
        }

        public GenericClass returnResult2()
        {
            return GenericClass.StaticFactory("Won't Compile, but it's clear that T is a string");
        }
    }
```

Error   1   Using the generic type 'SampleStatic.GenericClass' requires 1 type arguments

Why can't I do like the following with static members?

```
    public void ICanInferTheType<T1>(T1 item);

    public void returnResult4()
    {
        ICanInferTheType("Compiles, recognizes type string");
    }
```

Thanks -

Comment: Well the fix is to declare it with `GenericClass<string>.StaticFactory("A string");`

Comment: @ryanyuyu real fix indeed is to move factory to non-generic class with the same name... But that works too.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that makes sense since it's a factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @recursive! That answer is almost perfect, it requires one more  in the name of the method, like this:

```
public static class GenericClass
{
    // static factory method
    public static GenericClass<T> StaticFactory<T>(T resultData)
    {
        return new GenericClass<T>(resultData);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I missed that generic parameter declaration.  I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 7):

Generic inference only happens for method calls.  In your case, you need it for referring to a class.  Given `class GenericClass<T> { ... }`, any reference to `GenericClass` without a type parameter is a compilation error.  The only time generic parameters can be inferred is for generic parameters declared on method signatures.

However, you can achieve your goal anyway.  If you declare this additional class, you'll be able to invoke the method the way you want.  That's because the generic parameters are moved to the method.

```
public static class GenericClass {
    // static factory method
    public static GenericClass<T> StaticFactory<T>(T resultData) { 
        return new GenericClass<T>(resultData); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx this is going in the right direction, but if I add this as a separate class, it won't compile: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: Got it, it's missing the parameter in the function name StaticFactory<T> - posted the answer below, kudos to @recursive