# how to use generic in static class

Tags: c#, generics

I found static generic classes but that not works on net framework 4.7

Source:  http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-neat-little-type-inference-trick-with-c/

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public static Wrapper<T> Create<T>(T wrapped)
    {
        return new Wrapper<T>(wrapped);
    }
}
```

also found that but it says that the class is not a generic class
[C# Generics - Infer Type of static factory members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195524/c-sharp-generics-infer-type-of-static-factory-members)

Comment: This is NOT a static class, but a generic class containing a static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both the generic and non-generic versions of the class. The non-generic class calls the constructor of the generic one, therefore, it must be there.

This should work:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public Wrapper(T wrapped)
    {
        Wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public T Wrapped { get; set; }
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public static Wrapper<T> Create<T>(T wrapped)
    {
        return new Wrapper<T>(wrapped);
    }
}
```

Which you can use it like this as shown in the article you referred to:

```
var wrappedInt = Wrapper.Create(42);
```

Comment: ouh okay thanxs you